# How to implement Button_Click event handler to a custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create behaviour of my button. I checked solutions on other stackoverflow's problems. I don't know where I made a mistake. Here is the code:

```
class StartButton : Button
{
    public StartButton() : base()
    {
        this.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        this.Visible = true;
        this.Size = new Size(200, 50);
        this.Click += StartButton_Click;
    }
    void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Visual returns 2 errors: 
1)No overload for 'StartButton_click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'
2)The type or namespace name 'RoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'll be grateful for any solution

Comment: Are you coding this using a `WinForms` Control as base class?

Comment: no, I am trying to do it without using a WinForms

Comment: So, what's `Button` and where do those properties come from?

Comment: i'll add them in constructor. And I wanted to describe behaviour in Button_Click void, but I made something wrong, and I completely don't know where.

Comment: Yes, in the constructor, I can see that. But, from where do *them* (`Location` `Visible`, `Click`, ) come from? You do know that those properties and events are derived from the base class `Button` and that class is a `WinForms` class, here.

Comment: Yes, I checked that on learn.microsoft.com website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

```
void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

should be:

```
void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Just change `RoutedEventArgs` to `EventArgs`

Comment: That works! But there is 1 more error result: No overload for 'StartButton_click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'. It is in the line: "this.Click += StartButton_Click;"

Comment: Maybe You know how to fix it too?

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Forms.Button` type?

Comment: yes, i forgot to add this, i'm having this in code upper the class

Comment: Can you reply here with a screenshot of your actual code?

Comment: yes, but i didn't know how to paste it here. So i uploaded it on imgur https://i.imgur.com/zY0DEba.png

Comment: change `this.Click += StartButton_Click();` to `this.Click += StartButton_Click;`